# Spike when SKSpriteNode moves into screen area for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am developing a game in Swift 4 with SpriteKit, where I am facing an issue I have no idea how to fix or workaround it.

[- video link -](https://vimeo.com/310803041)

As you can see from the video, in my game I created a side menu (SKSpriteNode), which is outside the screen. He is placed on (minus) -screen_width. When I tap the menu button from the top corner, the side menu comes it with SKAction.move. First time the menu comes in, the application spikes, making the transition not running smoothly, easy visible to human eye.

My guess is: the first time the menu comes in, the application loads the images, creating the small spike. After I display the menu for the first time, the spikes no longer reproducing. Take into consideration the fact that the menu is created on didMove function, it's not created when the user taps the menu for the first time.

I encounter this problem every time I render a new object outside the screen and move it in. For example, if I create a bomb outside screen areas, for example (x: 0, y: 2 * screen_height), and then I put the bomb fall from the sky to player which is situated in the middle of the screen; when the image reach phone screen areas, it spikes.

Is there a way to force the application load the images before calling the menu in order to avoid the spike?

Comment: I don't know if this applies to UIImages, but calling a SKTexture's size property forces it to load into memory. Try calling it in the didMove func. Very nice looking app btw.

Comment: I was creating the menu in didMove and I attributed the texture as in example background.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "as_background"). Any other idea of how to to force loading it?